# In tcp server select() is invoked for every one second. how to differentiate two or more packets when they arrive with in "1 second"?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

i am calling select system call for every 1 second.if two or more packets arrives within one second. read() considering it as one packet. i want to know how many has arrived and also reading each packet separately?  please resolve the issue by not reducing that time "1 sec".

Answer (score 5):

TCP is a *streaming* protocol, which doesn't expose individual packets at the application level.

If you need to process individual packets, you will need to switch to a *datagram* protocol, such as UDP, which is designed for that kind of usage. Note, however, that this will require changes to both sender and receiver code, as well as a protocol redesign to manually handle retransmissions.

Comment: I know about udp.But My design requires Tcp.
Actually i am running this select on a thread for every "timeval"(1 sec) to avoid hangup of cpu/processor only to this function.(for better utilization of cpu time)

Comment: @user3056360 If your design "requires TCP", then you have no business reading individual packets. TCP is a streaming protocol and you should use it as such. If you need segments within the stream, see SHR's response. Also, I don't understand your "timeval" argument — the whole point of `select()` is optimal utilization of CPU time, because while select is waiting, the kernel schedules other threads and processes to run. Calling select() in one-second intervals is bad design.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it wrong, or else you need to describe more what you're doing. You normally call `select()` as frequently as possible and block waiting for input. Why are you clamping randomly at 1s? Whenever you're notified of readability, you always read greedily until you get EWOULDBLOCK/EAGAIN, at which point you go back to `select()` to wait for more input.

Answer (score 1):

For TCP you can define a protocol header and put the size in it (1,2 or 4 bytes, you need to define it).
for each signaled socket you can to do the steps

1. read header - size = "header size" (must be constant)
2. get the "data size" from header
3. read data size = data size (from step 2)
4. process packet
5. if there is more to read back to step 1.

**EDIT:**

if we 
let say this is your header:

```
struct header{
  int data_size; 
  //add more things if u like
};
```

in your code you read as usual but in 2 steps:

```
int res;
header hdr;
unsigned char data[MAX_SIZE];
res = recv(s, hdr, sizeof(hdr),0);
//now res should be = sizeof(hdr) 
res = recv(s, data,hdr->data_size,0);
//now res should be = hdr->data_size
```

now you have a full packet you can process.

Comment: thanks for the info .
could you please tell me how we can define a protocol header?

Comment: could you please tell me how we can read a protocol header without using raw sockets?

Comment: I didn't meant to tcp/ip header, define your own header, see the edit

Comment: I think the OP wants to read raw TCP headers. Your code processes parts of the stream, which you call packets, but which have nothing to do with IP packets.